# writing an adaptor removal tool, advice on ignoring case on the sequence

Tags: python, case, python-re

I am learning how to code. I need to code, among other things, an adaptor removal tool. My scripts works fine except in the cases where the sequence is a mix of lower and upper cases.
adaptor sequence== TATA
sequence == TAtaGATTACA

This is the function for the adaptor removal

```py
elif operation == "adaptor-removal":

    adaptor = args.adaptor 
    reads =  sequences(args.input, format)
    num_reads = len(reads)
    bases = "".join([read["seq"] for read in reads])
    adaptors_found = 0

    for read in reads:
        for i, j in read.items():
            if i == "seq":
                if j.startswith(adaptor.upper()) or j.startswith(adaptor.lower()):
                    adaptors_found += 1
                    j = j.replace(adaptor.upper(), "", 1) 
                    j = j.replace(adaptor.lower(), "", 1)                 
            args.output.write("%s\n" % j)
    print_summary(operation)    
    print("%s adaptors found" % adaptors_found)
```

I tried with:

```py
if j.startswith(adaptor,re.I):
```

but doesn't work, I don't really understand why. Can anyone experienced guide me through this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose `j` is `TAtaGATTACA` and `adaptor` is `TATA`.

Is `j.startswith(adaptor.upper())` true?  No, because `j` doesn't start with `TATA`.

Is `j.startswith(adaptor.lower())` true?  No, because `j` doesn't start with `tata`.

The easiest way to compare two strings case-insensitively is to convert both of them to the same case, upper or lower, and then compare those two strings as if you were comparing them case-sensitively.  It doesn't matter whether you choose upper-case or lower-case, as long as you choose the same for both.

Is `j.lower().startswith(adaptor.lower())` true?  Yes, because `j.lower()` starts with `tata`.

Also, take care with your two `.replace()` calls: it's possible that one of them may end up removing text further along in `j`, which I don't believe you want.  If you just want to trim the adaptor off the front of `j`, you are better off using a string slice:

```py
                if j.lower().startswith(adaptor.lower()):
                    adaptors_found += 1
                    j = j[len(adaptor):]
```

Finally, you also ask why

```py
if j.startswith(adaptor,re.I):
```

doesn't do what you want.  The answer is that if you pass a second parameter to [`.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith), the value of this second parameter is the start position that you search from, not a flag that controls the matching:

```py
"abcd".startswith("cd")           # False
"abcd".startswith("cd", 2)        # True
```

It happens that `re.I` can be converted to the integer 2.  So the following is also `True`, although it looks odd:

```py
"abcd".startswith("cd", re.I)
```

Comment: wow, looks so simple know... You can't imagine how many hours I spent with it. Thank you so so much.